# Validation rules for date and time in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, validation, codeigniter

I am using PHP CodeIgniter. I have kept validation in a function. I do not know the validation rule for date and time calendar in CodeIgniter. Can anyone give me an idea?

My code is :

```
$this->ref_valid_rules = array( 
                        array('field' => 'meeting_heading',
                              'label' => 'meeting heading',
                              'rules' => 'trim|required'), 
                        array('field' => 'meeting_agenda',
                              'label' => 'meeting agenda',
                              'rules' => 'trim|required'),
                        array('field' => 'venue',
                              'label' => 'venue',
                              'rules' => 'trim|required'),
                        array('field' => 'date',
                              'label' => 'date time',
                              'rules' => 'required') );
```

Comment: What is `$this->ref_valid_rules` ?

Comment: i kept that for validation rules

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('date', 'date time', 'regex_match[(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3(0|1))-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-\d{4}]');
```

http://www.formget.com/codeigniter-form-validation-date/

and other answers
[Codeigniter - Date format - Form Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14359158/codeigniter-date-format-form-validation)

[Date validation in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13666939/date-validation-in-codeigniter)

or you can try the set validation rules using callbacks

```
  function regex_date($date) {

    $data =  preg_match('@^Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|June|July|Aug|Sept|Oct|Nov|Dec-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}$@', $date);

    return $data;
}
```

the function will return true or false

Comment: function date_valid($date)
{
 $day = (int) substr($date, 0, 2);
 $month = (int) substr($date, 3, 2);
 $year = (int) substr($date, 6, 4);
 return checkdate($month, $day, $year);
}

Comment: Soproni; my date field is OK. but the format for the date field now is Feb-25-2015 14:06:08 . So how could i keep a validation for this..?

Comment: @Deepak Keynes;check again the answer

Comment: @Soproni ; I have kept my js code for date as <input type="text" id="demo4" placeholder="Click on the icon to choose date and time" maxlength="25" size="25"/><img src="/images/images/cal.gif" onclick="javascript:NewCssCal ('demo4','MMMddyyyy','dropdown',true,'24',true)" />

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own [callback](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks) function for validating the date.

Example below is for validating `dd/mm/yyyy` format so you can modify it as it fits your requirement. This is to give you hint about callbacks.

Pay attention to `callback_validate_date` in `set_rules()`. That's your callback function. It calles `validate_date()` behind the scene.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('date_field', 'Date', 'trim|exact_length[10]|callback_validate_date|xss_clean');
```

Callback

```
public function validate_date($date)
{
    //Some date fields are not compulsory
    //If all of them are compulsory then just remove this check
    if ($date == '')
    {
        return true;
    }

    //If in dd/mm/yyyy format
    if (preg_match("^\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}^", $date))
    {
        //Extract date parts
        $date_array = explode('/', $date);

        //If it is not a date
        if (! checkdate($date_array[1], $date_array[0], $date_array[2]))
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('validate_date', 'The %s field must contain a valid date.');
            return false;
        }
    }
    //If not in dd/mm/yyyy format
    else
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('validate_date', 'The %s field must contain a valid date.');
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```